# ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{..}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, onclick, nullpointerexception, simplecursoradapter

This question may look like a repeated one. But those queries hadn't helped me to fix my problem.

I would like to implement "onClick" event on the list (of baby names) which is populated with SimpleCursorAdapter. When ever the user clicks on a name, a toast will be generated showing the "id" of the record in the database.

Here is my code -

```
public class CommonNames extends Activity {

TextView rowview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.common_names);

    rowview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.commonName);

    CommonNamesAdapter cnTable = new CommonNamesAdapter(this);
    ListView cnListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.common_name_layout);

    cnTable.open(getApplicationContext());
    Cursor c = cnTable.fetch_all_common_names_only();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    if(c!=null){
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.listview,
                c,
                new String[] {c.getColumnName(0), c.getColumnName(1)},

                new int[] {R.id.rowLayout,R.id.commonName});

                cnListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }


    rowview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Context context = getApplicationContext();

            String id = context.getString(R.id.commonName);
            CharSequence text = "This id of this item is... "+id ;
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();

        }


    });
    cnTable.close();
}
```

Here is listview.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rowLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/commonName"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="14dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is common_names.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<ListView 
    android:id = "@+id/common_name_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height= "wrap_content" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I run my application I'm getting an Runtime NullPointerException. Here is the LogCat. Please help me in fixing this.

```
11-13 18:23:27.852: INFO/COMMON_NAMES_TABLE(775): Inserting record...
11-13 18:23:27.902: INFO/COMMON_NAMES_TABLE(775): OPening DataBase Connection....
11-13 18:23:28.002: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(775): Shutting down VM
11-13 18:23:28.002: WARN/dalvikvm(775): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-13 18:23:28.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 18:23:28.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{balu.android/balu.android.CommonNames}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-13 18:23:28.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-13 18:23:28.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-13 18:23:28.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-13 18:23:28.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-13 18:23:28.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-13 18:23:28.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-13 18:23:28.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-13 18:23:28.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 18:23:28.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-13 18:23:28.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-13 18:23:28.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-13 18:23:28.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 18:23:28.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-13 18:23:28.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775):     at balu.android.CommonNames.onCreate(CommonNames.java:42)
11-13 18:23:28.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-13 18:23:28.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-13 18:23:28.012: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775):     ... 11 more
11-13 18:23:28.032: WARN/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity balu.android/.CommonNames
11-13 18:23:28.032: WARN/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity balu.android/.Select
11-13 18:23:28.585: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{45025710 balu.android/.CommonNames}
11-13 18:23:31.192: INFO/Process(775): Sending signal. PID: 775 SIG: 9
11-13 18:23:31.212: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Process balu.android (pid 775) has died.
11-13 18:23:31.212: INFO/WindowManager(59): WIN DEATH: Window{45084738 balu.android/balu.android.BabyNamesAppActivity paused=false}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have a null value in CommonNames.java line 42. NPE are (often) the easiest fixable exceptions. You should learn how a debugger works. Try it! And by the way: An exception without the code is worthless for us... and no, nobody wanna browse github to search for the specific code...

Comment: Ok! I'll keep my code here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't set the onClickListener on the row view. That only sets the onClick event to one row and if there's no content it will crash (which is probably your problem)

try using

```
cnListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
    }
});
```

Comment: Agreed. It's crashing because there's no element with the `R.id.commonName` yet (so rowview is null). Since you're using a ListView, the actual components are rendered until the ListView itself is laid out, at some point during/after `onResume()`.

Comment: @Maria, I changed as you said. Now I'm getting another error. `
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(805): java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.widget.LinearLayout is not a  view that can be bounds by this SimpleCursorAdapter
11-13 19:42:04.462: ERROR/AndroidRuntime`

Comment: @dmon Here is the link to the error I got after implementing it in onResume() [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112491/error-androidruntime805-java-lang-illegalstateexception-android-widget-linea).

Comment: The problem is that in your adapter in the first column your trying to set the value to a LinearLayout (rowLayout). Add another TextView to your layout to display the content, or if it's just an ID remove the first value from your int[] and String []

Answer (score 0):

Your common_names layout has no view with id of `commonName` so `rowview`is null and `roview.setOnClickListener()` will NPE.

Actually by the error message of

```
...(775): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
...(775):     at balu.android.CommonNames.onCreate(CommonNames.java:42)
```

in the stack trace you pasted it should easy to pinpoint this, as the NPE is in CommonNames.java line 42